# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to make Google Map activity to find travel distance.But Unfortunately layout.xml file throw , below error and stop app. I used Min SDK version -  16.
I tried lot of thing to do but still error is remain.I run my app in real device.Expect some expert help.

```
2218/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{scpp.globaleye.com.scppclient/scpp.globaleye.com.scppclient.ui.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:258)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
                                                   at scpp.globaleye.com.scppclient.ui.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:44)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584) 
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.ad.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.h.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.y.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.bd.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.ev.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.z.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.y.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
                                                   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:807)
                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1013)
                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1112)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4676)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:258) 
                                                   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867) 
                                                   at scpp.globaleye.com.scppclient.ui.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:44) 
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020) 
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584) 
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My **MapsActivity** class. I comment other line and find `setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);` pass this error and stop app.

```
 public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    double start_lat,stop_lat,start_lng,stop_lng,lat,lng;
    Criteria criteria;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    String provider;
    Location location;
    Button start_btn,stop_btn;
    TextView tv;
    float[] distance = new float[1];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        //MapFragment fm = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        //System.out.println("on createteeeeeeeeeeeeeee");

        //SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        /*googleMap = fm.getMap();
        getLocation();

        //////button
        start_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        stop_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        stop_btn.setEnabled(false);

        start_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                //System.out.println("startttttttttttttttttttttttttbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
                if(tv != null){
                    tv.setText("");
                }

                stop_btn.setEnabled(true);
                start_btn.setEnabled(false);
                getStarrtLoc(location);

            }
        });

        stop_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                //System.out.println("stoppppppppppppppppppppppppppbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
                start_btn.setEnabled(true);
                stop_btn.setEnabled(false);
                getStoptLoc(location);
            }
        });*/

    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

        location = loc;
        //System.out.println("changggggggggggggggggggggggggg"+loc.getLatitude()+loc.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    public Location getLocation(){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //return;
            Toast.makeText(this,"NO PERMISSION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //return;
            Toast.makeText(this,"NO PERMISSION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if(location!=null){
            Toast.makeText(this,"GPS FIXED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //onLocationChanged(location);
            //return location;
            lat=location.getLatitude();
            lng=location.getLongitude();
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,0,0, this);
        //System.out.println("llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll"+lat+lng);
        return location;
    }

    public void getStarrtLoc(Location start_loc){
        start_lat = start_loc.getLatitude();
        start_lng = start_loc.getLongitude();
        //System.out.println("startttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt"+start_lat+"ffffffffff"+start_lng);

    }

    public void getStoptLoc(Location stop_loc){

        stop_lat = stop_loc.getLatitude();
        stop_lng = stop_loc.getLongitude();
        //System.out.println("stppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp"+stop_lat+"ffffffffff"+stop_lng);
        calcDistance();
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText("Distance :"+distance[0]);
        //System.out.println("dddddddddd"+distance[0]);
    }

    public void calcDistance(){
        Location.distanceBetween(start_lat,start_lng,stop_lat,stop_lng,distance);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
          super.onBackPressed();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, UserSelect.class);
            MapsActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            MapsActivity.this.finish();
        }
}
```

My **Activity_Map.xml** file.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MapsActivity">

    <fragment
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout1"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_maps" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="Start Ride"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <Button
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="Stop Ride"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/button2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button1" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

my androidMainfest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="scpp.globaleye.com.scppclient">


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <!-- To boot complete broadcast receiver -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <!-- External storage for caching -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >

        <!--
            The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
            (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
            Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
            You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
            sign the APK for publishing.
            You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
       -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBLN7wET4T0n6gu6Jr3AwE6jOQpqICkMBE" />

        <service
            android:name=".services.RemoteSenzService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>

        <activity android:name=".ui.Login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".ui.Home" />
        <activity android:name=".ui.Services_View" />
        <activity android:name=".ui.Update_Profile" />
        <activity android:name=".ui.UserSelect" />
        <activity android:name=".ui.Wallet" />
        <activity android:name=".ui.Registration" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: @Swordsman , please can u , do more explain what is mean ? [when I call this activity , Map_Activity.xml file ,throw this error and stop. you Said , the tag should be 'Fragment'] ? regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is because you are using a FragmentActivity, so you should use the SupportMapFragment and not the MapFragment (Because the support API Activity works with the Fragment class of the support library and not with the one of the base framework). Try changing this line

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

to this

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

As a side note, it's important to note that you should also use the AppCompatActivity instead of the FragmentActivity.

Comment: Why did you declare the "xmlns:map" namespace inside the fragment? You don't need it. What Google Play Services library version are you using?

Comment: remove it. but still same result.

Comment: What library version are you using?

Comment: device Android version 4.1.2 ,  buildToolsVersion "23.0.2", minsdk =16, classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3',  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'

Comment: And your compileSdkVersion?

Comment: 23 -compile sdk version. please ,I hope some reply and i search and use many solution given by other but unsuccessful.

Comment: can any one explain why down vote this. i think it is better give answer , even down voting.

Comment: sorry it is not about you. :)

Comment: @uma Did you add all the meta-tags that the Google Play Services requires?

Comment: ,are you want to see mainfest file ?

Comment: @uma It would be great (at least the part of the Google Play Services declaration). Also I don't know if the version of Google Play Services you are using requires the AppCompatActivity instead of the FragmentActivity. It would be great if you try to change that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122069/discussion-between-uma-and-josemgu91).

Answer (score 1):

I have just come across this exact error message after porting my test code into my production app.

In my case I forgot to include the following in the Manifest file:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

I had copied the string data just fine, but was buiding my Mainfest from scratch so missed the google maps api key information.

Hope this helps someone with the same issue.