# Google map API key issue

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I am developing an Android app using **Google maps**, to display current location of the user. I have generated an API key for **project package** as explained in Google API console. It worked fine and displayed the current location correctly. But when I share my code with a friend, it doesn't work saying "API key is not valid". Once she generate API key in her machine(different API key) it again work fine with that API key **only** in that machine, not work in mine.
Can anybody tell why that happened?? Isn't it generated for project package? Is it combined with MAC address or something?

Comment: You need to add your friend's pc's *SHA-1 fingerprint*. And need to add on *google developers console*.

Comment: this is hash key error when your computer is change hashkey is also change so this error is coming regenerate map key !!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39197832/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflating-class-fr this question discussion too ,may be help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://console.developers.google.com under your project add your friend's     SHA-1 certificate fingerprint (or) create one more android key for your friend with friend's SHA-1 certificate fingerprint

[image]

Comment: In release stage you should to add only key. It should be generate using release keystore file instead of your debug.keystore file